# scrollTop returning much lesser value for a div in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, scrolltop, fullpage.js

Reference Link: [http://old.crazyripples.com/?debug=1](https://crazyripples.com/?debug=1)

So, I am using jQuery and the jQuery fullPage plugin. It helps me achieve frame by frame scrolling.

Now, for internal divs where the vertical height is greater than the window height I have used some functions where I simply check for the scrollbar position and **stopPropagation** to the plugin so that inner scrollbar scrolls  without shifting the frame.

All works fine with chrome and since I built with chrome I used some calculations that I observed on chrome. But firefox is showing different results, **especially with scrollTop**.

I am aware of the fact that there can be a difference in height but if you see the logs in the reference link you will see, the height is almost the same(even if it isn't for you, its the scrollTop value that is an issue).

Here is the code that I am using to decide whether to stopPropagation or not.

```html
$(document).on("keydown",function(e){
    var story=$("#story"),
        story_con=story.find(".container"),
        story_top=story_con.scrollTop();

    if(story.hasClass("active")){
        // console.log(story_top,story_con.height(),story_con.innerHeight(),story_con.children("div").height(),story_con.children("div").innerHeight(),e.which);
        console.log("Div ScrollTop: "+story_top, "Container Height: "+story_con.height(), "Container InnerHeeight: "+story_con.innerHeight(),"Conatiner Div Height: "+story_con.children("div").height());

        //up arrow
        if(story_top==0 && e.which==38){
            console.log("prev frame")
        }

        //down arrow
        //chrome 280+432 >= 676 i.e. 712>=676 true
        //firefox 207+429 >= 676 i.e 636>=676 false
        else if(story_top + story_con.height() >=story_con.children("div").height() && e.which==40){
            console.log("next frame");
        }
        else{
            story_con.focus();
            console.log(story_con[0]);
            console.log("stopped propagation");
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
        return;
    }
});
```

And this is how I am calling the plugin:

```html
$('#main').fullpage({
    sectionSelector:'.frame',
    scrollingSpeed:800,
    responsiveWidth:1025,
    normalScrollElements: '#story, #startups, #services',
});
```

**Replication:**
Go to the reference link. Navigate to the second section(Our Story) by either scrolling, arrow keys or the menu. Now, only use arrow keys, the frame should scroll normally, but when the scroll completes, it should go to the next frame(does so in Chrome). See js logs for more details.

I would love it if anyone could help me in any way. I have been trying to debug this for sometime. Maybe I am focussing on the wrong issue? Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I know the plugin offers a **scrollOverflow** option. That was inducing more issues than this approach.

**Update:** Since I wasn't able to find any solution so specific, I changed my approach of detecting if the frame scrollbar had reached its end. I used this:

```
//down arrow
else if(container[0].offsetHeight + container[0].scrollTop >= container[0].scrollHeight){
    console.log("next frame");
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you use the `scrollOverflow` feature of fullPage.js to create the scroll bars as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html)?

Comment: The scrollOverflow option requires an external js file. Also, that option was not working stably for me. Maybe that I have used flexbox, might be the reason.

Comment: I would make sure you do not have problems on touch devices with your approach.

Comment: @Alvaro it is not a problem on touch devices(small size basically) as the fullpage plugin has an option to scroll the website normally when the browser width is less than the width I desire.

Comment: OK, didn't realize, you are probably the developer of the script :P Feel so lame! But I am so glad you are helping me with it!

Comment: I would open a new question without being so specific. Just ask how to get the same value for Firefox and Chrome for an scrollable element. You'll get far more answers having a short and more generic question.

Comment: If nothing helps, tell users not to use Firefox - I do so, it might not be the best practice, but it helps fix many issues.

Comment: "Not to use Firefox" you must be kidding me, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I really can't do that, its my own company's website.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Just to help my debugging. I am on version 49.0.1 and your keydown function currently works on any screen size with a width larger than 1024.

Comment: Also, just so you know your `div#services` is currently too tall (even on an iMac display) to use 1 arrow down keypress to transition.

Comment: If you could provide a code snippet or a jsfiddle that can be executed, that would help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

*This is the start of my answer as I continue to debug to give you better details.

Currently using Firefox version 49.0.1 on window sizes smaller than 1280px your content inside your `container` classes are too tall.

Current proof:
In your divs, `#story`, `#partners`, and `#services`, if you where to give the `div` that is the direct child of `div.container` in each of the major sections a `height: 200px` all of your arrow down keypresses will work.

**Edit 1**
In magic.js line 111 is where your issue starts.

`else if(story_top + story_con.height() >=story_con.children("div").height() && e.which==40){`

The content within each of your containers, `story_con.children("div").height()`, is sometimes greater than `story_top + story_con.height()` so it does not go into the next page path that you desire.

Of course this all depends on the height of the window.

Your debug logging proving my point:
[image]

Comment: OK, first of all thanks a lot for helping. Now, I resized my window to 1280 and it works fine in chrome. Actually, it works on chrome regardless of the dimensions. In firefox(same version), I set the div.container>div height to 200px and it works but it has a simple reason for that. For a height less than the window, no scrollbar would be present and the condition on line 111 evaluates to true and the next frame is loaded.

Comment: This is true for any height of the div less than the window height. Now, the line 111 simply means that if the arrow key is down and we have reached the end of the scroll position. All calculations would run properly if the story_top variable(scrollTop) would result in a value same as chrome, which it doesn't.

Comment: Okay :) I will look into why scrollTop is different in Chrome vs Firefox

Comment: It seems .scrollTop() doesn't work well in Firefox. After work today I will try to write out a work around for you

Answer (score 0):

The Simple answer would be because Chrome and Firefox render pages differently. To understand why you get the differences in rendering have a look at this [Explanation](http://www.unumux.com/ux-insights/2016/2/24/subpixel-troubleshooting)

I hope this clears it out.

Comment: I am actually aware of that. But in this context I don't know if it helps. First of all, I am not dealing with widths, its a height and scrollTop issue. Maybe, it might deal in a similar manner with heights, but the only height I have given is 100vh and there is only 1 child. Even if I somehow believ that is the real issue, 5-10 px difference will make sense but if you see the logs, there is almost 80px difference(for me) in the Chrome and Firefox values. So, I guess that is not the reason.